# Cannot release (Unity) ARCore App for Android / Conflict in Android manifest

Tags: android, android-studio, unity-game-engine, android-manifest, arcore

I've been having a problem releasing my Unity ARFoundation app for weeks now, as it simply doesn't suggest any compatible devices to me. When queried by the Playstore, the answer I've always been given is:

"I've looked into your issue and found that your app is not compatible with the most of the devices due to a conflict in your app's manifest with the following Missing device feature:android.hardware.autofocus, android.hardware.camera.ar, com.google.ar.core.depth.
For more information [...]"

However, I have edited the Android manifest several times in Android Studio.
I integrated all missing , used standardized manifests for ArCore (https://de.acervolima.com/wie-erstellt-man-eine-einfache-augmented-reality-android-app/) and tested many things. I also created a new app, with a new release. However, there are always 0 devices suggested.

Does anyone perhaps know about Android AR releases?

Kind regards

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

-<manifest android:versionName="1.0" android:versionCode="4" package="com.paradys.viewinterior" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="31" android:minSdkVersion="25"/>

<!-- This helps to permit the user to access Camera -->


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<!--This helps to check a specific feature in the phone's hardware,here it is OpenGl ES version 3 -->


<uses-feature android:required="true" android:glEsVersion="0x00030000"/>

<!-- Here it is checking for AR feature in phone camera -->


<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.ar" android:required="true"/>

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="true"/>

<uses-feature android:name="com.google.ar.core.depth" android:required="true"/>


-<application android:extractNativeLibs="true">

<meta-data android:name="com.google.ar.core" android:value="required"/>


-<activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity" android:theme="@style/UnityThemeSelector" android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait" android:resizeableActivity="false" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:hardwareAccelerated="false" android:exported="true" android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|fontScale|layoutDirection|density">


-<intent-filter>

<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>

</intent-filter>

<meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true"/>

<meta-data android:name="android.notch_support" android:value="true"/>

</activity>

<meta-data android:name="unity.splash-mode" android:value="0"/>

<meta-data android:name="unity.splash-enable" android:value="True"/>

<meta-data android:name="unity.launch-fullscreen" android:value="True"/>

<meta-data android:name="unity.allow-resizable-window" android:value="False"/>

<meta-data android:name="notch.config" android:value="portrait|landscape"/>

<meta-data android:name="unityplayer.SkipPermissionsDialog" android:value="true"/>

</application>

</manifest>
```

The merged manifest is.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

-<manifest android:versionName="1.0" android:versionCode="5" android:targetSandboxVersion="2" android:installLocation="preferExternal" package="com.adamcherry.viewinterior" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="31" android:minSdkVersion="25"/>

<supports-screens android:xlargeScreens="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true"/>

<!-- This helps to permit the user to access Camera -->


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<!--This helps to check a specific feature in the phone's hardware,here it is OpenGl ES version 3 -->


<uses-feature android:required="true" android:glEsVersion="0x00030000"/>

<!-- Here it is checking for AR feature in phone camera -->


<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.ar" android:required="true"/>

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="true"/>

<uses-feature android:name="com.google.ar.core.depth" android:required="true"/>

<!-- 权限配置 -->


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"/>

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.autofocus"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>


-<queries>

<package android:name="com.google.ar.core"/>

</queries>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>


-<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@mipmap/app_icon" android:extractNativeLibs="true" android:appComponentFactory="androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory">

<meta-data android:name="com.google.ar.core" android:value="required"/>


-<activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity" android:theme="@style/UnityThemeSelector" android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait" android:resizeableActivity="false" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:hardwareAccelerated="false" android:exported="true" android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|fontScale|layoutDirection|density">


-<intent-filter>

<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>

</intent-filter>

<meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true"/>

<meta-data android:name="android.notch_support" android:value="true"/>

</activity>

<meta-data android:name="unity.splash-mode" android:value="0"/>

<meta-data android:name="unity.splash-enable" android:value="True"/>

<meta-data android:name="unity.launch-fullscreen" android:value="True"/>

<meta-data android:name="unity.allow-resizable-window" android:value="False"/>

<meta-data android:name="notch.config" android:value="portrait|landscape"/>

<meta-data android:name="unityplayer.SkipPermissionsDialog" android:value="true"/>

<!-- The minimal version code of ARCore APK required for an app using this SDK. -->


<meta-data android:name="com.google.ar.core.min_apk_version" android:value="210910000"/>

<!-- This activity is critical for installing ARCore when it is not already present. -->


<activity android:name="com.google.ar.core.InstallActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.Dialog.Alert" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:exported="false" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" android:excludeFromRecents="true"/>

<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.actions" android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>


-<provider android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true" android:authorities="com.adamcherry.viewinterior.provider">

<meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>

</provider>

</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Looks like a typo, so `<uses-feature android:name="google.ar.core.depth" android:required="true"/>` should be `<uses-feature android:name="com.google.ar.core.depth" android:required="true"/>` from https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/depth/developer-guide#restrict_access_to_depth-supported_devices

Comment: I changed it, but it is still not working